# Opening a Knowledge Article in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

Is there an equivalent of `$Action.KnowledgeArticle.View` in lightning component?

I am displaying a list of articles in lightning component, but not sure how to implement the mechanism of user being able to click on the article title in the list and open the actual article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm) has a list of available components, I encourage you to browse through it in the future. You will notice the force:recordView component can be used to view a record in Read-only mode. As long as you are able to get the record Id when you select the title, you should be able to pass it to the component.

Please include your code in future posts in ordere to be able to better assist you.